# 10000ms elapsed without getting a service from the pool - JSS SSR default nodejs pool size - Integrated mode

Tags: jss

Sitecore 9.3 + JSS.
Under heavy load we see errors in log files:

```
Exception Message
Exception: System.TimeoutException
Message: 10000ms elapsed without getting a service from the pool.
Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node
  at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.GenericConcurrentPool`1.CheckOut()
  at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
  at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
  at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
  at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
...
```

NodeRenderEngine tryes to render a component and takes a INodeServices from the GenericConcurrentPool but cannot because as I see from the code `PoolSize` is not defined in the config.

```
<renderEngine name="nodejs" patch:source="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config">
<instance id="defaults">
<!--

              If true, the Node.js instance will accept incoming V8 debugger connections (e.g., from node-inspector).
              The node process is invoked with the "inspect" flag.
            
-->
<LaunchWithDebugging>false</LaunchWithDebugging>
<!--

              If "launchWithDebugging" is true, the Node.js instance will listen for V8 debugger connections on this port.
              IMPORTANT: Node instances _must_ have unique debugging ports. If you try to create multiple node instances with the same debugger port, those node processes will exit.
              Therefore, it is recommended that you create <instance /> configurations for individual JSS apps / renderings if you wish to use remote SSR debugging features.
            
-->
<DebuggingPort/>
<!--
 If set, the Node.js instance should restart when any matching file on disk within your project changes. 
-->
<WatchFileExtensions>.js|.json|.html</WatchFileExtensions>
<!--

              If set, starts the Node.js instance with the specified environment variables.
            
-->
<EnvironmentVariables>
<var name="NODE_ENV" value="production"/>
</EnvironmentVariables>
<!--
 Specifies the maximum duration, in milliseconds, that your .NET code should wait for Node.js RPC calls to return. 
-->
<InvocationTimeoutMs>10000</InvocationTimeoutMs>
<!--
 Specify the path to node to execute. 'node' = resolve using PATH environment variable 
-->
<NodePath>node</NodePath>
</instance>
</renderEngine>
```

but has value `2` from the `<app name="defaults" ... serverSideRenderingWorkerProcesses="2"`.

So the question is: should I increase the pool size and what is the general rule here besides the  'one per cpu core' coming from the common sense?

Answer (score 2):

My case is solved with the node version.

Our hosted environment is azure appservice and node version is 8.

The issue was solved when I changed the latest node version in the app service. Change below in app service

[image]

```
"name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
"value": "~18"
```

Answer (score 1):

From my testing in Prod of a Vue JSS 18 app in integrated mode, on a server with 4 cores, the best performance came from setting `serverSideRenderingWorkerProcesses="1"`. This is counter-intuitive but the results speak for themselves. However I was still getting the issue, just at higher loads.

[Sitecore docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/jss-topologies.html):

> We do not recommend integrated mode for heavy load production scenarios, because the entire page is server-side rendered using Node.js as a block, not as individual renderings. Therefore, traditional output caching mechanisms become all-or-nothing. In other words, if caching is enabled, it forces caching of the entire page, which is almost always not what is desired.

I think this will always be an issue in integrated mode - it is just a limitation. Better option is to work on getting headless mode working.